# Trying to run Ko-Fi widget inside a React component. Running <script> commands inside DIV

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, script-tag

So, here's the script I have to run in order to implement a Ko-Fi widget on my website.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ko-fi.com/widgets/widget_2.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  kofiwidget2.init('Buy me a coffe!', '#3c807c', 'XXXXXXXXXX');
  kofiwidget2.draw();
</script>
```

My website is a Single Page App built with React, so here's what I'm doing.

**1** - I moved the script that loads the `widget_2.js` to the `<head>` of my `index.html` file:

**index.html**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ko-fi.com/widgets/widget_2.js'></script>
```

Should I add the `async` to this script tag?

**2** - I'm trying to load the rest inside my React component, but without success, so far:

I tried:

```
// NOTE: IT'S DISPLAYING AS MULTI-LINE HERE JUST TO MAKE IR MORE READABLE
return(
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 
    "<script type='text/javascript'>
       kofiwidget2.init('Buy me a coffee!', '#3c807c', 'XXXXXXXXXX');
       kofiwidget2.draw();
     </script>"
  }}>
);
```

And also:

```
return(
  <div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      kofiwidget2.init("Buy me a coffee!", "#3c807c", "XXXXXXXXXX");
      kofiwidget2.draw();
    </script>
  </div>
);
```

And nothing seems to happen.

**EXTRA INFO:**

The `kofiwidget2.draw();` method does the following:

```
draw: function () {
  document.writeln(style + html.replace("[color]", color).replace("[text]", text).replace("[id]", id));
}
```

It uses the `document.writeln` method. So I guess this should be run exactly where I need the button to be loaded. I.e: Inside the div.

**SNIPPET (TRYING TO RUN A SCRIPT COMMAND INSIDE A DIV IN REACT)**

```js
function App() {
  return(
    <script type="text/javascript">console.log('TEST_1');</script>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: I'd probably put the Ko-fi button on a separate *.html document and simply display it using an `<iframe />`. Writing directly to the document is the antithesis to everything React.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have this bad feeling about iframes, though. I avoid'em at all costs. I'm trying to implement it using `useEffect` and `useRef`. Will update the question if I can make it work.

Comment: The only alternative I see is to render the button outside your react app using the Ko-fi script tag, then grab it and append it inside your app. However, if the only reason for not using an iframe is a bad feeling, why not find an actual reason supported by knowledge or ignore it?

Comment: Well, I turned it into a React component: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-sun-49mzk

Comment: @ChrisG thanks! I've ended doing something like that as well (got rid of the `widget.js` and refactored their button into React, using styled-components). You should post that as an answer here. Regarding iframes, I may give them another chance at some point, but the fact that they become basically another website inside your own site and you [can't style them unleed you have cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe) is pretty much why I choose not to work with them unless there's absolutely no other option. While using React I haven't felt that need yet. Tks

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of solutions to this on the internet (trust me, I searched forever). I wanted to use the interactive widget. Here was my solution. It's pretty similar to one of yours, but slightly modified. I'm working in nextjs as well.

add
`import Head from 'next/head'`

At the top of your function component add

```
<Head>
     <script src='https://storage.ko-fi.com/cdn/scripts/overlay-widget.js'/>
</Head>
```

Create a string to make your life easier:

```
const kofi = 
`<script>
  kofiWidgetOverlay.draw('pixelbakery', {
    'type': 'floating-chat',
    'floating-chat.donateButton.text': 'Tip Us',
    'floating-chat.donateButton.background-color': '#ff5f5f',
    'floating-chat.donateButton.text-color': '#fff'
  });
</script>`
```

inside your component somewhere:

```
 <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: kofi }} />
```

Comment: I am using react and had success with the npm package`kofi-button` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/kofi-button). It seems like this package does something similar to what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for those using `next.js`

Add the following to `layout.tsx` or `layout.js` just before the closing tag for the `body` element.

Make sure to `import Script from next/script` at the top of the page.

```
  {/* Kofi Donations */}
<Script src='https://storage.ko-fi.com/cdn/scripts/overlay-widget.js' strategy='beforeInteractive' />
<Script id="kofi-donations" strategy='beforeInteractive'>
   {`kofiWidgetOverlay.draw('<kofi_page_name>', {
    'type': 'floating-chat',
    'floating-chat.donateButton.text': 'Tip Me',
    'floating-chat.donateButton.background-color': '#5cb85c',
    'floating-chat.donateButton.text-color': '#fff'
   });`}
</Script>
```

Using the `Script` element and setting the `strategy` to `beforeInteractive` seems to be the key. If you find this to be acceptable my kofi page is [here](https://ko-fi.com/chrisdixononcode), but I'll settle for an upvote.